# Correponding C# code for VB ThreadStart calls

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have these lines in VB and want to know the C# equivalent of them . I have converted the code using online converter but I am not sure. So need some expert advice

```
Dim PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate As New ThreadStart(AddressOf PlotLensProfileThreadFunction)
    Dim PlotLensProfileThread As New Thread(PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate)
    Dim PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate As New ThreadStart(AddressOf PlotLensPlanThreadFunction)
    Dim PlotLensPlanThread As New Thread(PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate)
```

The online tool resulted in this

```
ThreadStart PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensProfileThreadFunction);
Thread PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate);
ThreadStart PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(PlotLensPlanThreadFunction);
Thread PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);
```

I was getting errors into the above code , so I did something like this and its working.

```
ThreadStart PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(new FrmSoftJobProcess(). PlotLensProfileThreadFunction); //This has to be revisited again
        Thread PlotLensProfileThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess(). PlotLensProfileThreadDelegate);
        ThreadStart PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(new FrmSoftJobProcess().PlotLensPlanThreadFunction);

        Thread PlotLensPlanThread = new Thread(new FrmSoftJobProcess().PlotLensPlanThreadDelegate);
```

The function **PlotLensProfileThreadFunction** is defined in the same class FrmSoftJobProcess and is **non static** . As it is non static- compiler was not letting me access it so I had to pas it along the class name

```
 private   void PlotLensProfileThreadFunction()
        {
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag =FrontEndStructures. InitErrorFlag();
            Graphics InMedia = this.PicLensPlot.CreateGraphics();



           PlotLensProfileThread PlotRef = new PlotLensProfileThread();
           // var PlotRef = PlotLensProfileThread;
            try
            {
                PlotRef.ThreadInGrphRef = InMedia;
                PlotRef.ThreadInConcavePaths = ConcavePaths;
                PlotRef.ThreadInConvexPaths = ConvexPaths;
                PlotRef.ThreadPlotOptions = PlotOptions.ProfileView;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepSixData = JobData.StepSixData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepFiveData = JobData.StepFiveData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepFourData = JobData.StepFourData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepThreeData = JobData.StepThreeData;
                PlotRef.ThreadStepTwoData = JobData.StepTwoData;
                PlotRef.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag;
                PlotRef.MeridianConcave = MeridianConcave;
                PlotRef.MeridianEdge = MeridianEdge;
                PlotRef.MeridianConvex = MeridianConvex;
                ZedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
                PlotRef.zedGraphType = ZedGraphControl1;
                PlotRef.PlotLensProfile();
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException e)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
        }
```

Just want to know was it the right approach I took or there could have been something else ?

I dont know where the **AddressOf** Operator went that was in the VB code

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's hard to give an accurate answer without truly knowing where your `PlotLensProfileThreadFunction` and others are defined. For me, the online tool results seem to be far better, than your version (nl, to create a new instance inline and assign a method delegate to the threadstart process (and for all 3 threads you are making a new FrmSoftJobProcess) ). `AddressOf` is not needed in C#.

Comment: let me update the question for you with the function defination

Comment: @Icepickle can you check ? the online version was giving errors as the method was not static . So had to do like that .

Comment: Any chance you could make a minimal complete verifiable example? Write some basic code of what you are trying to do in VB.net, then use your online tool to see the difference in C# and then post this code for your example? You could then rework the mcve into your real code

Comment: See my answer to your original question - it matters greatly that these are 4 fields, and not local variables. In C#, instance fields cannot reference other instance fields in their declarations.